# Tinymce plugin library files which are need

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using the tinymce jquery plugin the version 3, there I have included the whole folder which I downloaded from their site, and linked the script in my jsp.
Here I need to link only one script file as you know. **jquery.tinymce.js** I have did that, but for using the advanced theme still I need to add some supported script files too.
I am not getting which are the only required files we need to add so I end up in adding the whole folder I guess which is not required.
Here is my project folder where I added the complete folder. [image]

In the image we you can see the only file we are linking in jsp.
The question is what are the only required files I need to keep so that tinymce works fine with advanced theme and I want to remove the unwanted files and scripts which I am not making use of them.
Can anybody suggest me what are the files which are required.

Answer (score 0):

You can fully remove the "examples" folder under tinymce.

I don't advice to delete any further, because normally the size of files is small and not worth the trouble. If you do want to continue deleting you can remove license.txt and start removing unnecessairy plugins : 
Example give : if you don't want to use the Emoticons (found under plugins), delete the folder. All information on the plugins in TinyMCE 3.X can be found here [http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:Plugins](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x%3aPlugins)